# Getting around let arguments in Swift

Tags: swift, var, let

Here's a simple playground example:

```
class Foobar {
    var name = ""

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func modifyName(modification:String) {
        self.name += modification
    }
}

let list = [Foobar(name:"I"), Foobar(name:"Me"), Foobar(name:"Myself")]

for each in list {
    each.modifyName(" rules")
}
```

A class with `name` variable, and a single function that can modify that variable. Make a list of them, now use a `for in` to exercise the modifying function.

BUT. If I refactor the modifyName variable into a protocol extension:

```
class Foobar {
    var name = ""

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

protocol Modifiable {
    var name:String { get set }
}

extension Modifiable {
    mutating func modifyName(modification:String) {
        self.name += modification
    }
}

extension Foobar:Modifiable { }
```

Then the `for in` will no longer work because the `Modifiable` extension needed to annotate the `modifyName` as `mutating`. The error emitted is `error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'each' is a 'let' constant`. There's a simple workaround, but it feels like I'm abusing something:

```
for each in list {
    var each = each
    each.modifyName(" rules")
}
```

I've had the same problem with functions that have an argument that has been tagged with annotating. It used to be the case that you could mark those parameters with `var` in the arg list, but that is deprecated in the latest versions of swift. The same single line workaround works there. Is there a better more idiomatic way to do this? What originally started this, was simply extracting some common behavior into protocol extensions, rather than an inheritance tree. It feels like I'm paying a penalty for that choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, your single-line workaround doesn't necessarily work. Your protocol does not require that conforming types are reference types (classes). If a struct conformed to your protocol, and were in the array, `var each = each` would make a **copy**, and modifying the copy would not modify the value in the array.

You could require your objects to be classes, `protocol Modifiable: class`, in which case I believe `mutating` will no longer be allowed (or, at least your code will work properly).

But presuming you want to keep `mutating`, you can do this to modify the elements in place:

```
for i in list.indices {
    list[i].modifyName()
}
```

Of course, your array will also have to be `var`, because it's also a struct with [value semantics](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10).

Comment: I did not know about the `class` modifier for protocol declarations. That helps tons, thanks!